# Php creating hours except lunch hours

Tags: php, date, time

I'm creating an appointment system. Hours creating automatically 10 by 10 but I need to remove lunch hours these are 12:00 between 13:00 from 24 hour date time system.

```
$start=strtotime("08:30");
$end=strtotime("17:30");
$now=$start;                
while($now <= $end){
    echo '<option value="'.date("H:i",$now).':00">'.date("H:i",$now).'</option>';
    $now = strtotime('+10 minutes',$now);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add lunch time:

```
$start=strtotime("08:30");
$end=strtotime("17:30");
$startLunch=strtotime("12:00");
$endLunch=strtotime("13:00");
$now = $start;
// and then you can use it in your while loop:
while($now <= $end){
    if($now < $startLunch || $now > $endLunch)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.date("H:i",$now).':00">'.date("H:i",$now).'</option>';
    }
    $now = strtotime('+10 minutes',$now);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$start=strtotime("08:30");
$end=strtotime("17:30");
$lunch_start=strtotime("12:00");
$lunch_end=strtotime("13:00");
$now=$start;                
while(($now <= $end) && ($now >= $lunch_start || $now <= $lunch_end)){
    echo '<option value="'.date("H:i",$now).':00">'.date("H:i",$now).'</option>';$now = strtotime('+10 minutes',$now);
}
```

Comment: It still display lunch hours